# How to Add Content Description to Existing Android Dialog

Tags: android, android-dialogfragment

I am reusing the AlertDialog for Android (reference here: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/AlertDialog.html).

I need to add content descriptions to the dialog's buttons. Is there a way to do this without making a full custom Android Dialog?

Comment: What components of the dialog in particular do you need to add content descriptions to?

Comment: In general, controls with text shouldn't have content descriptions since the goal of an accessibility service is to provide parity between the visual and spoken (or Braille, etc) user experience. Are you sure you need to set a content description?

Comment: @alanv. Good points. Unfortunately, for the way that another application is interacting with this one, it needs to have content descriptions on the text buttons.

Comment: In my code, Talkback is pronouncing an acronym in the text, and a content description would be the obvious way to fix that.